# Visual Basic Error Message

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to Visual Basic so I realize this question is remedial... when I try to run my program using the following code I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I realize similar questions have been asked but I want to display my code which is the folowing:

```
Private Sub txtGrade1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtGrade1.TextChanged

    Dim numGrade As Decimal

    numGrade = CDec(txtGrade1.Text * 0.15) + CDec(txtGrade2.Text * 0.25) + CDec(txtGrade3.Text * 0.2) + CDec(txtGrade4.Text * 0.4)
    MsgBox("Your Grade is" + numGrade)

End Sub
```

I have no idea what is going on here. The program will allow me to put in 1 digit in the text box when it runs but then I get the error message

Comment: declare numGrade as String

Comment: You have to do the multiplication outside the (). Your current code is trying to multiply txtGrade.Text * 0.15 and then convert using CDec(). Convert first and then multiply: `numGrade = CDec(txtGrade1.Text) * 0.15 + ` and so on.

Comment: Each of the txtGrade# textboxes need to have a valid number in them - a blank won't do. However, there's a little cheat you can use, the Val() function, which will make a blank into a zero. E.g. `CDec(Val(txtGrade1.Text)) * 0.15`. Smarter, though, is to learn to use the Decimal.TryParse method instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, give this a try for MsgBox: `"Your Grade is" & numGrade`.

Comment: Make this the first line in your file `Option Strict On`, and your IDE will guide you through all your errors.

Comment: You should understand why this is wrong: `txtGrade1.Text * 0.15`, String times float. How do you define this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this will solve your type mismatches. But you may not want to show a message box *every* time `txtGrade1.Text` changes...

```
Private Sub txtGrade_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtGrade1.TextChanged
    Dim grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4 As Double
    If Double.TryParse(txtGrade1.Text, grade1) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade2.Text, grade2) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade3.Text, grade3) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade4.Text, grade4) Then
        Dim grade = grade1 * 0.15 + grade2 * 0.25 + grade3 * 0.2 + grade4 * 0.4
        MsgBox(String.Format("Your Grade is {0}", grade))
    End If
End Sub
```

To improve upon your code, you could make this happen when any of the `TextBoxes` are *validated* instead of changed, since if you are typing 99, the change event fires after the first 9 is typed. The Validated handler fires when you move out of the `TextBox`.

```
Private Sub txtGradesValidated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles txtGrade1.Validated, txtGrade2.Validated, txtGrade3.Validated, txtGrade4.Validated
    Dim grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4 As Double
    If Double.TryParse(txtGrade1.Text, grade1) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade2.Text, grade2) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade3.Text, grade3) _
            AndAlso Double.TryParse(txtGrade4.Text, grade4) Then
        Dim grade = grade1 * 0.15 + grade2 * 0.25 + grade3 * 0.2 + grade4 * 0.4
        MsgBox(String.Format("Your Grade is {0}", grade))
    End If
End Sub
```

Still not ideal, as you will see if you test it. You could also consider KeyPress or KeyUp and only perform the logic on <kbd>Enter</kbd> press but this changes the logic and design of your program so it's up to you.